# Adding same property:value pair to multiple objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, push

I have two arrays, which are almost identical in structure, except for one has a `property:value` pair on every object, and the other doesn't.

### Newcastle Array (*with* `clubCode` property)

```
 [
            {"clubCode": "newcastle-united",
                "firstName": "Tim",
                "lastName": "Krul",
                "position": "gk"},

            {"clubCode": "newcastle-united",
                "firstName": "Rob",
                "lastName": "Elliot",
                "position": "gk"}
]
```

### Arsenal Array (*without* `clubCode` property)

```
 [
            {"firstName": "Petr",
                "lastName": "Cech",
                "position": "gk",

            {"firstName": "David",
                "lastName": "Ospina",
                "position": "gk"}
]
```

Is it possible to `push()` the `clubCode` property to *every* object within the Arsenal array, so I don't have to manually add it to every single one?

...so each object starts with `"clubCode": "arsenal"`.

Or if there is any other solution I'd love to hear it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: on which basis  you want to add it and how is your final data structure look?

Comment: I'm running AngularJS, and I'm accessing the `$scope.arsenalSquad` array by calling a JSON file, which is that same array. The array is returned as `arsenalSquad.data`. In my controller, I want to write the necessary code to return every object within that array with the property of `clubCode` and the corresponding value of `arsenal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) over your data structure.

```
var x =  [
            {"firstName": "Petr",
                "lastName": "Cech",
                "position": "gk",
            },
            {"firstName": "David",
                "lastName": "Ospina",
                "position": "gk"}
         ]; 

x.forEach(function(e){e.clubCode='arsenal';})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) at this context,

```
arsenalArray = arsenalArray.map(function(itm){
  return (itm.clubCode = "arsenal", itm);
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/phLg2yp7/)

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. My problem is, I'm pulling the arsenalSquad array from a JSON file and the Service I'm using is returning it as `arsenalSquad.data`. So my final code looked like this: `$scope.arsenalSquad.data = $scope.arsenalSquad.data.map(function(itm){
  return (itm.clubCode = "arsenal", itm);
});` Can you see what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.ar1 = [
            {"clubCode": "newcastle-united",
                "firstName": "Tim",
                "lastName": "Krul",
                "position": "gk"},

            {"clubCode": "newcastle-united",
                "firstName": "Rob",
                "lastName": "Elliot",
                "position": "gk"}
];

    $scope.ar1.forEach(function (value) {
      value.clubCode = "newcastle-united";
    });

    console.log($scope.ar1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy using lodash.js

_.assign(arsenalArray, { clubCode: "arsenal" });

Comment: That does look easy. Would that work in AngularJS? My issue is I'm using a Service to pull the arsenalSquad array from a JSON file, and it's returning the array as `arsenalSquad.data`. So, in your case, would I write: `_.assign(arsenalSquad.data, {clubCode: "arsenal" });`?